# Array of sounds with .plist file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Here is my code:

MainViewConroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {

    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
    NSArray *soundsArray;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *soundsArray;

-(void)prepareSounds;
- (IBAction)playSound:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

Here is my MainViewController.m:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController 

@synthesize audioPlayer;
@synthesize soundsArray;

-(void)prepareSounds
{
    NSString *filepath= [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"plist"];

    self.soundsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

}

- (void)stopAudio
{
    if (audioPlayer!= nil) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
        //do some task for changing the Image i.e setting the default image
    }

}

- (IBAction)playSound:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender;

    NSString *soundName = [soundsArray objectAtIndex:(btn.tag - 1)];

    NSString *path      = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundName ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *file         = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path];

    AVAudioPlayer *p    = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:nil];

    self.audioPlayer    = p;

    if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
    {
        [self stopAudio];
    }

    [self.audioPlayer play];


}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Flipside View

- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender
{    
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

@end
```

I have 3 buttons.  In the 'Supporting Files' folder I have an array of strings with the name of the sound files I want to play, named 'Sound.plist', and in the 'Supporting Files' folder I have a folder named 'Sounds', which contains the sound files.

All of my buttons play the same sound, even when I delete the .plist file.  It seems to always play the sound that is first in the 'Sounds' folder.  Can someone please provide some insight, I feel like I have tried everything. Thanks!

Comment: are `button.tag` values the same?

Comment: @holex: no, they get incremented as 1, 2, 3